# Is there any way to add icon in overflow menu item?

Tags: android, overflow-menu

[image]

I'm using overflow menu in basic Navigation Drawer.

And I want to display icon and text at menu item.

But whatever I do doesn't work.

These are the ways I tried in menu.xml code.

First, It's an ordinary way to put 'android:icon'
overflow_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MovieList">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_movie"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="setting1"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_gallery"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:title="setting2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings3"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="setting2"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Second, Using 'android:actionLayout=""' code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MovieList">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_movie"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="setting1"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/overflow_menu_title"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_gallery"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:title="setting2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/overflow_menu_title"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings3"
        android:orderInCategory="150"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/overflow_menu_title"
        android:title="setting2"

        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

overflow_menu_title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_15"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MOVIE"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to any way but everyting failed.

I don't know why I can't put an icon in it.

please help me...

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a `PopupMenu` with your `overflow_menu.xml`.

Create a function in your activity to initialize the popup:

```
private void setupPopupMenu() 
{
    ImageButton menuButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_button)

    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, menuButton);
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_movie:
                    break;
                case R.id.menu_gallery:
                    break;
                case R.id.settings3:
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Then call this function in your `onCreate` method.

If you are using a default `Toolbar` or the default `ActionBar` from the Android theme you may want to implement your custom `Toolbar` layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:text="Title"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menu_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:src="<your-button-image>"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also, simplify your `overflow_menu` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MovieList">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_movie"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="setting1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_gallery"
        android:title="setting2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="setting2" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm so sorry but I'm using Java. So I don't understand your popup code..

Comment: sorry..I failed...Popupmenu does not show.. :(

I'm using Navigation Drawer Activity provided by Android.

Is that the cause?

Comment: Yes, in my solution I assume that you will use a normal Activity with a parent `LinearLayout` and the custom toolbar I suggested. I don't think that you can display icons in the popup menu of the default Toolbar.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this programmatically in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method using [`MenuBuilder`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0-source/androidx/appcompat/view/menu/MenuBuilder.java.html) class, and setting `setOptionalIconsVisible(true)`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, menu);

    // Force showing icons for menu items
    if (menu instanceof MenuBuilder) 
        ((MenuBuilder) menu).setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    
}
```